# IIS7 is only compressing ASPX files when I'm accessing the site from the server locally

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, compression

I have a .net 4.0 site running on IIS7.  Compression is enabled in IIS manager, and I see the folder C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files exists.  I am using Chrome and an extension ySlow to perform analysis on the site.

When accessing the site locally, I can see in the ySlow information pages that the aspx file requested is compressed using gzip.  It lists the unzipped and zipped size.  And when viewing the headers, I see "Content-Encoding: gzip".  This works whether I access the page using localhost, the server name, or IP address.

When accessing the same page from another client (using the server name OR IP Address), the page is not gzipped.

This one has me stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: "another client" What client?

Comment: Laptop running Win7 Pro, with FF and Chrome.  Based on other SO questions, I've also added noCompressionForProxies="false" to my sites httpCompression config section.